# Filter footprint array has incorrect shape for skimage.filters.median

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

[image: Fig 1]

skimage.filters.median has no problems for Fig 1, but errors of **filter footprint array has incorrect shape** for Fig 2.
What is the reason?

[image: Fig 2]

```
from skimage import io, filters
import skimage.morphology as morph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = io.imread("test.png")
im = filters.median(im, morph.disk(5))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
```

Comment: It is likely a color image (3D array). Convert to gray scale before applying the median filter.

Comment: replace line 5 with `im = io.imread("test.png", as_grey=True)` and you should be good

Comment: The option is named `as_gray` according to the latest documentation.